# How to create an IIS7 re-write rule for a single category

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I have a WordPress installation on an IIS7 server. I am currently using permalinks with a setting of /news/%category%/%postname%/ so the URL for all my category landing pages are in the form of /news/{category name}.

I have now set up a category that i do not wish to follow this general pattern. Instead of using the url /news/newcat I would like to use just /newcat.

So far I have been able to set up a rule in my config file as follows:

```
   <rule name="67" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="newcat/" ignoreCase="true" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="news/newcat" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

This does the job but it changes the URL in the address bar - I'm greedy and want everything - redirect the page and show the URL as the 'new' url.

My next thought was to do a rewrite instead and this is where I get stuck. I've tried:

```
    <rule name="wordpress2" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="newcat/" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?category_name=newcat" />
    </rule>
```

and a few variations but without success. Can anyone advise please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly suggest leaving IIS alone and implement your requirements in WordPress:

```
/**
 * Remove category base from "newcat" permalink.
 *
 * @param   string  $link
 * @param   object  $term
 * @return  string
 */
function wpse_175424_term_link( $link, $term ) {
    if ( $term->taxonomy === 'category' && $term->slug === 'newcat' )
        $link = home_url( user_trailingslashit( $term->slug ) );
    return $link;
}

add_filter( 'term_link', 'wpse_175424_term_link', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Add our custom rewrite rule to the top of category rules.
 *
 * @param   array   $rules
 * @return  array
 */
function wpse_175424_category_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $matches_1 = $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 );
    $new_rules = array(
        'newcat/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => "$wp_rewrite->index?category_name=newcat&feed=$matches_1",
        'newcat/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => "$wp_rewrite->index?category_name=newcat&feed=$matches_1",
        'newcat/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => "$wp_rewrite->index?category_name=newcat&paged=$matches_1",
        'newcat/?$' => "$wp_rewrite->index?category_name=newcat",
    );

    return $new_rules + $rules;
}

add_filter( 'category_rewrite_rules', 'wpse_175424_category_rewrite_rules' );
```

You'll need to flush your rewrite rules after adding the code (simply visiting the Settings > Permalinks page is sufficient).

Note that I've hardcoded `newcat` throughout the two functions - if you needed this to be flexible & pulled by ID/option it's easy enough.

Comment: Thank you for your response however I cannot seem to get this to work. I added the code you provided to the functions.php for the active template and then went to the settings > permalinks page as advised. Is there anything else I need to do ?

Comment: Have you definitely replaced *all* instances of `newcat` with the actual category slug?

Comment: Fair question, but yes I definitely have. The error I get is a 403 server error if that helps.

Comment: Problem solved. I actually had a stray folder with exactly the same name as the category I was creating. Simply changing the name of this folder fixed the code.